# Why is my project no longer updating when I write new code?

Tags: python, django, reactjs, localhost

I have a react / django app. The django side hosts a sqlite database, and react displays its content as the front end. When I run the command `python manage.py runserver` it is hosted locally on port 8000. My specific problem is manifest when I make edits to my React code. Even after refreshing the page and restarting the server, my front-end still remains as it was before I had edited the code and saved. I have no errors, or warnings.

The only way I seem to be able to make it work is by pushing to GitHub and then cloning the repository on my system again. Would anyone be able to help me understand my dilemma? (Please let me know if my question is not to par with the guidelines of Stack Overflow, this is my first time)

Comment: Perhaps a browser issue? Have you tried force reloading the page after server restarted using `Ctrl+Shift+R`?

Comment: @ZWang Yea I thought it was my browser as well, I have restarted the page in several ways. But from what I'm searching online I think I might be dealing with some sort of cache? I have yet to find an answer. Stack Overflow might be my best bet.

Comment: Force reload forces all the css files to reload, to change the look. Clearing the cache will do the same thing. What's the actual issue? Are new js functions not working or just alignment issues e.t.c.

Comment: @StephenHorton try to use `touch settings.py` on you Django settings

Comment: @ZarakiKenpachi looks like it doesn't recognize that command for me. I am in a `pipenv shell` as well. And I was cd'd into the root folder containing `settings.py`..

Comment: @ZWang I don't know how to clear the cache. And the actual issue is that my page is not updating to represent the actual code that I've written. It reflects the previous version since I edited my code. Meaning the functions/jsx/etc are not firing / not representing what I have in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently I was supposed to be running `npm run dev`. Started working after that.